# JSON parse returns empty string?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I am not sure if this is an issue about VueJS or JS itself.

I have string in my DB (converted JS Object with JSON.stringify() ) which looks like this:

`{"type":5,"values":{"7":"/data/images/structured-content/64-7-scico.jpg","8":"<b>wefwe</b>","9":"Nějaký text","10":"/data/images/structured-content/64-10-scico.jpg"}}`

What I wanted to do is select it from database (via Axios), convert it back to JS object and set it to VueJS data:

```
.then(response => {

            if (response.data.response === "ok" && response.status == 200) {

                // get data
                let data = response.data.data.data[0];

                // pass name to state
                this.objectName = data.name;

                // get json in string format
                let result = data.content;

                // first log
                console.log(result);

                // convert string to json
                let content = JSON.parse( result );

                // second log
                console.log( content.values );

                // update states
                this.IDType = content.type;
                this.values = content.values;


            }

        })
```

**Axios**, **data.name** and **content.type** works fine, however the second log (**content.values**) seems to be returning observer with empty strings which I can't pass to Vue data and work with it, as you can see on the screen below, values in this object are just empty no matter what I do.
What is exactly wrong in here? Thank you!

[image]

from debugger:

[image]

Comment: Log a specific member, not the entire object.

Comment: That works, but I need to add entire object to my Vue data and thats the problem, I tried to trick it like so:

                ```Object.entries(content.values).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                    this.values[key] = val;
                });
                console.log(this.values);```

but no success

Comment: The values are fine, you're just trying to use them too early. Hover over the small blue `i  icon on the console message ...

Comment: @Teemu That is certainly possible, I just don't understand what to do and how is that possible? I am trying to work with data that axios returns after it's resolved as always and the data is obviously there, how come I am trying to use them too early? And what can I do then?

Comment: If the values exist in the preview (red text) but not the dropdown it implies they existed when the console.log was initially made but subsequently lost. Can you try adding `debugger;` immediately after `console.log( content.values )` ?

Comment: @ellisdod I edited the question and added screen from debugger too if it helps

Comment: Are you able to console.log content.values['8'] ?

Comment: @ellisdod yes, this logs properly, I guess this request goes for getter, that is within observer, so it works -  but when I tried to create empty object, than loop through this observer and fill this object with values and keys one by one, it came out exactly the same -> keys are attached, but values are empty

Comment: Can you share your data object and props for this component?

Comment: I have following props: 

```props: ["data", "pageID", "groupID", "objectType"]```

Data:

data() {
      return {
          isLoading: true,
          ScTypes: [],
          objectName: "",
          IDType: 0,
          values: {},
          fields: {},
          newImages: {}
      }
  }


Generally in mounted() I am calling Axios api which returns me string with this json, after axios promise is resolved I am trying to parse it and set it to VueJS Data as "values" object

Answer (score 0):

To be reactive Vue needs to know what the keys of an object are before you assign them. So if they are known, pre assign them:

```
data : () => ({
  values : {
     7 : "",
     8 : "",
     9 : "",
     10 : ""
  }
}),
```

Then use object assign to set them:

```
Object.assign(this.values, content.values)
```

If the keys are unknown / dynamic values you can set them to be reactive using the `$set` method:

```
Object.keys(content.values).forEach(
  function(key){
     this.$set(this.value, key, content.values[key])
  }
)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, no matter how I tried to apply your solution, always getting my data to "this.values" in form of observer thats not really working